# My Code Works with two files but not with 3 or more? .glob() taking files from a folder python

Tags: python

This code works for one or two files in a folder but returns 'ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 3 elements, new values have 2 elements' when I have 3 or more files in the folder. The files I've been using are all very similar .csv files.

```
def read_file(UI):
    user_input = UI
    path = r'C:\\Users\\CP\\documents\\reporting\\' + user_input
    allFiles = glob.glob(path + '/*.csv')
    frame = pd.DataFrame()
    l = []
    for f in allFiles:
        df = pd.read_csv(f,index_col=None,header=0)
        l.append(df)
    frame = pd.concat(l,ignore_index=True)
    return(frame)
```

This is an example of the data in the csv files I'm using.

```
Campaign            Total Ad Spend
CP_AMOB_LRX_101611  0.17854
CP_CARS10_LR_774470 0.48159
CP_CARS11_LR_774471 0.17724
CP_CARS9_LR_774469  0.92701
```

Comment: Looks like your CSV files have different number of columns. Could you post examples of these files, please?

Comment: That's what I thought but I went through every file and they all have the same number of columns, nothing out of place, no rogue commas...

Comment: with csv's in numpy, I found I would generate a phantom column/row if i even clicked on a cell (without putting anything in it). Given that you show 2 columns, but the error message says it is expecting 3, I think that this might be the case.

Comment: how would I get around this? Incorporate 'Phantom Columns' in my code?

Comment: delete the phantom columns in the csv (in Excel, I just did right click -> delete column) or add some way to manipulate the data before trying to combine them, but I don't know how glob works, and wouldn't know how to do that

Comment: Is there a way that you ensure this doesn't happen outside of deleting columns?

Comment: I tried deleting columns and re-saving the documents but I still get the same error :(

Comment: with numpy, i 'process' the data into another numpy array before I do anything with it to make sure to avoid having 10 columns instead of 9. I would suggest adding something similar, but I wouldn't know how to do that in `glob`. (Of course, this isn't necessarily the problem)

Comment: can you recommend another function which would grab each file in a particular folder?